Is there a model or some implementation logic for web layouts?
I am making an application in which the user types BDD scenarios of using a webpage. From this retrieve the widgets and their functionalities and make a "webpage prototype" in Figma. I am however struggling with the layout. Right now I am just inserting the widgets on each of the pages in a grid based on what the user wrote first.
Does anyone know of a way to make the layout better? It doesnt have to be perfect as the user is allowed to just drag to widgets around afterwards. I was thinking there must be some models out there capable of giving me x,y coordinates for the widgets but I haven't be able to find any.
So basically, in short format: Given the widgets of a webpage (with their attributes such as the text on the button and such), I want to have some x,y positions returned that I can use.
I have tried using ChatGPT in the results were kinda meh. Besides, I want it to be a solution that is free and not make an API call that costs money...

"I want to have some x,y positions returned that I can use." — can you give more information about what you mean and what problem you are trying to solve?

Thank you for answering! I am trying to automatically generate web prototypes from text a user has written in BDD format: given the browserwindow "login page" is shown, and the textfield "username" is not empty, and the textfield "password" is not empty, when I click the button "login", then the browserwindow "home page" is shown. This would extract two pages, one with two textfields and a login button. I have done this parsing and inserted them into the figma prototype but just in a grid like layout. I was wondering if I could use some llm to return x and y coordinates for each of the widgets

... based on what it thinks makes sense. So it knows that typically a menu would be in the header, or that images are typically showcased in the body in a grid like fashion, or maybe that icons or logos should be shown in certain places. I was just hoping someone had trained an existing model already, but I had no luck finding any

Yes, I know of a way to make the layout better: I show my first scetch of the UI to one or two users and discuss it with them. That's an old, praxis-proven, standard software engineering technique.
From what you wrote, I guess that is not the kind of answer you were looking for, but honestly, it sounds like you are trying to solve a people problem with a technical solution, and that rarely works.

Websites tend to all follow similar templates. I would simplify the problem by providing a selection of page templates with areas, then having the code generate the template choice with a list of controls in order per area. Rather than x,y coords.
If each area is setup with a flow, ie top down justified one per row, left right word wrap at width etc Then you should be able to produce sensible looking results
